# Retrieving file name with Javascript (without URL?)

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver, filenames, spry

I need to retrieve the file name of an HTM file - the file needs to retrieve its own file name - to use in another Javascript function within the same file. So far I have -

```
var Docname = "ESSA_CL_2009_01"
var DSstem = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("ESSA10_DA_sourceData_19_1.xml", "ESSA_CL_2009/" + Docname + "/Item_stem");
```

(the Spry or AJAX stuff is already set up)

The var Docname I'd like to be generated dynamically. It doesn't have a URL yet as such - I don't have any control over its final destination.

Any help  would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is `ESSA_CL_2009_01` in that case?

Comment: ESSA_CL_2009_01 is the filename without .htm suffix if I were to do things manually. However I want to do things dynamically, so I want code to replace the first line of code I put in in the above. I'm thinking (contrary to what I first stated) it does still have a URL .. I just need the file name without the its preceding URL content and without the suffix.

Comment: Now as it happens a similar problem was discussed at http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/386.htm .. The code provided there to retrieve the filename from the URL was as follows:

var url = document.URL; 
var Docname =(url.substring(url.lastindexOf("\\")+1,url.lastindexOf("\."))); // for windows 
var Docname =(url.substring(url.lastindexOf("\/")+1,url.lastindexOf("\."))); // for *nix 
document.write(Docname);

For whatever reason this doesn't appear to work..

Answer (score 1):

If the "Docname" refers to the current page's static file path, then you can use document.location.pathname to get the pathname portion of the URL, and then parse that as a string to grab only the portion you desire.

Comment: Thanks.. um - there won't be a static file path: The final destination location of the file will be different and is unknown.. Using var url=document.URL would seem to be be the right way to go as an initial line of code, rather than pathname (?) - but it doesn't work either .. (I did try var url=document.location.pathname;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var getFileName = function (uri) {
  var fileName = uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  return fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
};
```